# c3.js : How to rotate the labels above the bar-chart bar items?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, c3.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpsom.png

How to rotate these values? (Open link above) I'm using c3.js last version.
Thank you for your help.
**Simple example:**

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Value', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        labels: true
    },
});
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: My question is direct and illustrative but thanks for the comment.

Comment: http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_rotate.html

Answer (score 2):

There's no c3 setting for this like there is for the axis labels, but you can rotate them using some d3 code within the [onrendered](http://c3js.org/reference.html#onrendered%20/onrendered) callback:

```
onrendered: function () {
    d3.selectAll(".c3-chart-texts text.c3-text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var textSel = d3.select(this);
            return "rotate(90, "+textSel.attr("x")+", "+(textSel.attr("y"))+")";
        })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return (d.value && d.value > 0) ? "end" : "centre";
        })
    ;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfjm0gLh/1/